# Embedded Google Calender Events Not Showing

Tags: html, google-calendar-api

I am helping improve a website for a local organization. We want to add a Google Calendar to the website so I set off writing the code to accomplish this. I wrote a blank html page just to test the functionality so I don't have to publish it to the site until it's ready. I have got it displaying in the webpage, but it is not showing any of the events. I get the impression they do not sync to the actual calendar, so every single month we will have to re-embed the calendar, can anyone confirm this for me or am I missing something? I have looked all over for an answer to this, but everyone just says to check the sharing setting and make sure it's public. I have done so, and it is. The functionality I am looking for is that the calendar is embedded and I can add events to it through Google and it should display those newly added events to the embedded calendar, is this how the embedded calendars work and I just missed something basic?
Here is the html code I am using:

```
<iframe class="calendar" src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=5ptfkiqbvpup2gfo62gdfaig7o%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FDenver" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It's wrapped in a div inside the body and there is nothing else on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to refresh the page of the embedded calendar in order for the event to reflect.

[image]

The event reflected in my page upon refresh.

You can use Calendar API's [Incremental synchronization](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync), using this method, you can keep data for all calendar collections in sync while saving bandwidth. If you'll use this, you have to create your own calendar implementation for your website rather that embedding your calendar to your site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have refreshed the page many times. Both the html file I have written as well as the actual google page where I can edit the calendar and add events and no luck. The embedded calendar still does not show any new events. With the API I could just use some javascript to fetch the events then and use them how I need to?

Comment: SOOOOO I have figured out my problem. -__- I was adding events to the wrong calendar because google defaults to my person calendar, even if I have the public calendar active. So if anyone else is having this issue, make sure your events are being added to the proper calendar. I do like the idea though of implementing my own calendar and using google's api to fetch events.

Comment: I forgot to say that hehehe. Just make sure you're adding it to the correct Calendar

Comment: Well I was being an idiot and it shouldn't have needed to be said haha